# using Zgrep and awk to parse a .tgz file and print first row

Tags: awk, grep, zgrep

I would like to use Zgrep and Awk to print specific lines.

I use the below script. However, I am not able to print the specific line requirement.

zcat SYS.20210519.tgz | awk '/11055/ && /2.5.5.5/'

It would be nice if someone could help. Thanks.

File name   :  SYS.20210519.tgz

File INPUT :

```
20210519 072532  11055  ERROR   Connection is not writable, error[grpId[2.5.5.5/49.3.14.13:17126] connId[142706130] testMode[true] connInfo[ConnInfo[connId=142706130, connGrp=2.5.5.5/49.3.14.13:17126,
```

File output (Needed) :

```
20210519 072532  11055  ERROR   Connection is not writable, error[grpId[2.5.5.5/49.3.14.13:17126]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts, please do add your samples of input and expected output more clearly in your question to make it clear.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have edited my question now with the input file and expected output file. Thanks

Comment: I have edited my Question again. Thanks

Comment: In what way is your script failing? It **would** print the line you want (plus maybe some others you don't want but idk if that's the problem you're asking about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Using `zcat` to read your Input_file then sending its output as standard input to `awk` program. Where using `match` function to match regex, which will print till value of error[grpId till `]` occurrence.

```
zcat Input_file | 
awk 'match($0,/.*error\[grpId\[[^]]*\]/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```